# Undefined crash c++ highload network application

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

С++ Network application.
Multi-threaded application - 20 threads
In each thread, 200 new connections created per second.

Crashes intermittently on error

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==3518897=-ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f4a980000b0 (pc 0x7f4a980000b0 bp 0x7f4acbffeb40 sp 0x7f4acbffeaf8 T3521225)
==3518897==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==3518897==Hint: PC is at a non-executable region. Maybe a wild jump?
#0 0x7f4a980000b0 (‹unknown module>)
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV (‹unknown module>)
==3518897==ABORTING
```

With the same periodicity, an error occurs on the function "malloc" in different places in the program or the connected "libevent" library.

Looks like the "malloc" function is not thread safe.

In which direction to look for a solution to this error?

Comment: I guess this is an important program if it is getting 200 connections per second on a server. Are you able to reproduce the problem on your own computer with simulated connections?

Comment: Getting multi-threaded code 100% correct is hard.  A thorough bench check might be a good idea, making sure that mutexes or whatever are being appropriately locked (and unlocked!) when they should be.  And you might use things like [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to help make the code bullet-proof.

Comment: The logical direction is to run this under a debugger or grab a core dump and try to reconstruct the stack from the `sp` register here. My best guess given this information is either a dangling pointer or a use after free.

Comment: Analyze the callstack of the crash. Protect your data and your pointers (members) with std::mutex, std::scoped_lock (or std::unique_lock). Make sure objects shared between threads are owned by shared_pointers (or are guaranteed to have the same life cycle as your whole program). And write stress tests on smaller bits of your code, find the minimum bit of code that (re)produces a problem.